# How to add markers at certain x coordinates using Sympy plot

Tags: python, sympy

I have a Sympy function, a sequence of x coordinates and a graph drawn using "plot".

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')
xs = np.linspace(-2, 3, 5) #[-2.   -0.75  0.5   1.75  3.  ]
ys = sp.cos(2*x)*(sp.sin(2*x) + 1.5)+sp.cos(x)
graph = sp.plot(ys, xlim=[-2,3])
```

**How could I draw markers on the function at X coordinates from xs variable?**

The graph I get:
[image: Graph]

The graph I would like to get:
[image: Prefered graph]

Comment: To get the corresponding y-coordinates: `[ys.subs(x, xi).evalf() for xi in xs]`

Comment: See [How To Graph Points With Sympy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289609/how-to-graph-points-with-sympy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sympy's plot [supports a `markers=` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469474/how-do-i-use-the-markers-parameter-of-a-sympy-plot/71478683#71478683).  This is a list of dictionaries towards matplotlib's [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). Sympy's `subs` can be used to fill in an x value into the formula.

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')
y = sp.Symbol('y')
ys = sp.cos(2 * x) * (sp.sin(2 * x) + 1.5) + sp.cos(x)

xs = np.linspace(-2, 3, 5)  # [-2.   -0.75  0.5   1.75  3.  ]
yvals = [ys.subs(x, xi) for xi in xs]

plot = sp.plot(ys, xlim=[-2.2, 3.2],
               markers=[{'args': [xs, yvals, 'ro']}])
```

[image: sympy plot with markers]